# Block for CallState not invoked iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I am trying to monitor the callStates.I implemented an own class for this with this init method:

```
- (id) init
{
self = [super init];
if (!self) return nil;

callCenter = [[CTCallCenter alloc] init];

[callCenter setCallEventHandler: ^(CTCall* call) {
    if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateConnected]) {

    } else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateDialing]) {

    } else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateDisconnected]) {

    } else if ([call.callState isEqualToString: CTCallStateIncoming]) {

    }
    NSLog(@"\n\n callEventHandler: %@ \n\n", call.callState);
}];

return self;
}

@property(nonatomic, strong) CTCallCenter* callCenter;
```

I linked the CoreTelephony Framework in my Project...But the Block never gets called...If i put the same Code in my AppDelegate, it works...

Des it only work in AppDelegate?!

UPDATE:

I allocate my Class in my AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
VoiceReceiver *v __attribute__((unused)) = [[VoiceReceiver alloc] init];
....
}
```

Comment: where and how is the class created / stored. Would bet its getting released

Comment: Did you add voip to UIBackgroundModes ?

Comment: i allocate the class in my AppDelegate like this:VoiceReceiver *v __attribute__((unused)) = [[VoiceReceiver alloc] init];

Comment: @marcio You don't need Voip for this purpose...

Comment: @chrizstone thats not at all helpful. If you do that on a single line inside a callback, its going to be dealloc'd at the end of the function. Please post the FULL code showing where it is done. Don't put it in a comment, edit your question

Comment: @chrizstone added an answer. For future reference, if its not a comment on my answer I don't get notified of you comments unless you use the `@` symbol and my name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
VoiceReceiver *v __attribute__((unused)) = [[VoiceReceiver alloc] init];
....
}
```

Will not work. As soon as this callback is finished `v` will be dealloc'd.

If you need to use it in the appDelegate. Make the calss a property in the .h and init it where you are now.

e.g.

appDeletage.h

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) VoiceReceiver *voiceReciever;
```

appDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    voiceReciever = [[VoiceReceiver alloc] init];
    ....
}
```

The key difference here is that the appDeleagte is a singleton that will always be in memory so long as the app is running. Adding a `strong` property to this means it won't be removed unless the app crashes.